# Remove all characters before a period in a string

Tags: regex, r, string

This keeps everything before a period:

```
gsub("\\..*","", data$column )
```

how to keep everything after the period?

Comment: `.*?\\.` should do it.

Comment: If there is only one period, use negation. `^[^.]*\\.`

Answer (score 30):

To remove all the characters before a period in a string(*including period*).

```
gsub("^.*\\.","", data$column )
```

Example:

```
> data <- 'foobar.barfoo'
> gsub("^.*\\.","", data)
[1] "barfoo"
```

To remove all the characters before the first period(*including period*).

```
> data <- 'foo.bar.barfoo'
> gsub("^.*?\\.","", data)
[1] "bar.barfoo"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `stringi` with `lookbehind` regex

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_first_regex(data1, "(?<=\\.).*")
 #[1] "bar.barfoo"
 stri_extract_first_regex(data, "(?<=\\.).*")
 #[1] "barfoo"
```

If the string doesn't have `.`, this retuns `NA` (it is not clear about how to deal with this in the question)

```
 stri_extract_first_regex(data2, "(?<=\\.).*")
 #[1] NA

###data
data <- 'foobar.barfoo' 
data1 <- 'foo.bar.barfoo'
data2 <- "foobar"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to think about the regex for this the `qdap` package has the `char2end` function that grabs from a particular character until the end of the string.

```
data <- c("foo.bar", "foo.bar.barfoo")

library(qdap)
char2end(data, ".")

## [1] "bar"        "bar.barfoo"
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
gsub(".*\\.","", data$column )
```

this will keep everything after period

Answer (score 0):

`require(stringr)`

I run a course on Data Analysis and the students came up with this solution :

```
get_after_period <- function(my_vector) {    

        # Return a string vector without the characters
        # before a period (excluding the period)

        # my_vector, a string vector

        str_sub(my_vector, str_locate(my_vector, "\\.")[,1]+1) 

        }
```

Now, just call the function :

```
my_vector <-  c('foobar.barfoo', 'amazing.point')

get_after_period(my_vector)

[1] "barfoo" "point"
```