# Extract part of a column value to new variable (mutate)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df like this:

```
v1
a.1  
b.3
cz.90
```

How can I create a new column equal to:

```
v1     v2
a.1    1
b.1    3
cz.90  90
```

After the "." I could have numbers that go from 1 all the way to 999 so cannot do it based on a specific position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all characters before a period in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991824/remove-all-characters-before-a-period-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression with `sub`, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(New = as.numeric(sub(".*\\.","",v1)))

     v1 New
1   a.1   1
2   b.3   3
3 cz.90  90
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the strings with `.` as delimiter

```
library(stringr)
# this will create a 2 columns matrix, first column: what comes before .
# second column what comes after
# number of rows = number of rows in df
split_matrix <- str_split_fixed(df$v1,fixed("."),2)
# assign the second column from split_matrix to df$v2
df$v2 <- as.numeric(split_matrix[, 2])

df
#     v1 v2
#1   a.1  1
#2   b.3  3
#3 cz.90 90
```

Edit since your question contained `tidyverse` tag, you can do it that way:

```
df%>% mutate(v2=as.numeric(str_split_fixed(df$v1,fixed("."),2)[,2]))
```